# Is Silverlight on Windows CE R3 not in sandbox?

Tags: silverlight, windows-ce

Silverlight on Windows CE 6 r3 is different I know, it's Silverlight 2 with a native C++ backend. But is this backend locked down in any way?

Can I access the local file system etc?

I'm currently building a proof-of-concept for a client, and I don't want to show them this lovely UI if I can't deliver on the functionality in the future.

I assume it is 'full trust' and has no restrictions?

Someone let me know as soon as possible please :)

Cheers,
Ash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - you can access the local file system from your Embedded Silverlight 2 application.

You can read the following blog post to see how to set a Silverlight application - [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210120074020/http://geekswithblogs.net/WindowsEmbeddedCookbook/archive/2009/10/11/silverlight-for-embedded-tutorial-step-2.aspx).

The blog has a couple of more posts that go through a basic Silverlight application.

By going through the code you will notice that in the C++ code you can do whatever you like. You can link your application against any native Dll and call whatever API you want.